# Using the infinity symbol while solving improper integrals

Tags: limits, notation, indefinite-integrals

Is it correct to use the infinity symbol while solving definite integrals, like so:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\,dx$$ $$=\ln(x)\,\Big|_1^\infty$$ $$=\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}\left(\ln(b)-\ln(1)\right)$$

or does one have to start putting in the limits in the previous steps, like so?

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\,dx$$ $$=\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}\int_1^b \frac{1}{x}\,dx$$ $$=\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}\left(\ln(x)\,\Big|_1^b\right)$$ $$=\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}\left(\ln(b)-\ln(1)\right)$$

Comment: I believe the second longer notation is the "expansion" of what people normally understand by writing the first one. It's always a limit, so you don't have to forget this. It's not a raw substitution. You always operate in the limit way. So both are correct.

Comment: Warning: In the second case you assume that you can interchange the limit with the integral, which is not always possible. So be careful with that.

Comment: @FourierTransform Thank you for the info. If the first way is indeed correct and an acceptable way to write it, please write your comment as an answer to this question so that I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the second longer notation is the "expansion" of what people normally understand by writing the first one. It's always a limit, so you don't have to forget this. It's not a raw substitution. You always operate in the limit way. So both are correct.

**Warning**: In the second case you assume that you can interchange the limit with the integral, which is not always possible. So be careful with that.